# Perspective Issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I have an issue with perspectives. I am trying to draw lines onto this 3D rectangle in the mage below to create a block paving type effect. If you've never seen block paving, it's square blocks of granite.

Here is the image:

[image]

I've tried placing the lines in manually, but when I get to the middle, it seems off. I want some sort of symmetry on either side so the lines look like their going into the distance.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

GIMP has the perspective transform tool:

http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-perspective.html

What you'd probably end up doing is creating a normal 'straight' grid of lines in a separate layer with a transparent background, and then using the perspective transform to make the grid lines converge. Squish it down vertically to fit the dimensions of your slab, and you should have the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thought not precisely what you asked for, the [Vanishing Point Tool](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/photoshop/articles/phs9avrvanpt.html) is very helpful for this type of work.  You may want to better familiarize yourself with this tool.